# Making menu of QToolButton pop on the left instead of bottom ? Is it possible?

Tags: c++, qt, qmenu

Is it possible to have the QMenu popup on the left of QToolButton instead of the bottom.
I am currently doing something like this

```
QMenu *menu_contacts = new QMenu("Contacts",this);
menu_contacts->setStyleSheet(menu_sheet.c_str());

QAction *actaddContact = new QAction(menu_contacts);
actaddContact->setText("New Contacts");

ui.toolButton_3->setMenu(menu_contacts);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code in onclicked `SLOT` of your `toolbutton`

```
  menu_contacts->popup(mapToGlobal(ui->toolButton->pos()-
                      QPoint(menu_contacts->sizeHint().width(),0)));
```